# Blank R charts in Kaggle and Knit rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I am new to R and I am currently finishing my first case study, its a part of the google data analytics course. I wrote all my code in my R markdown and it works perfect in the console and R studio but I noticed when I went to knit the file none of my charts showed. The plot would appear but it was fully blank, I didn't really think much of it because I mainly wrote it so I can put it on Kaggle. So I copy everything over to Kaggle and for some reason the same thing is happening and I cannot figure out why.

I rechecked all my code and everything ran, I tried to check different options I couldn't find anything online. I don't know what to do. So I uploaded my kaggle notebook to the public and I am hoping someone can help me. https://www.kaggle.com/code/cmjeremyray/bellabeat-case-study This is the notebook if you scroll down you can see the barren plots, thank you in advance for the help.

Also this is an example of some code in the notebook, this runs fine in R studio but once I knit or have it in Kaggle its an empty plot.

````r
`ggplot(data = activity_sleep_daily) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = totalminutesasleep, y = calories)) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = totalsteps, y = calories)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 900)) +
  labs (title = "Daily Total Sleep and Calories Burned",
        x = "Total Minutes Asleep",
        y= "Calories Burned")`
``` r
````

Comment: Welcome to SO, @CMJeremyRay! I myself did that cert & assignment. Lots of people will be willing to help you here, but standard (perhaps req'd) practice here is to post not a pic or link but actual data and code sufficient for a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Should I post every code I ran?

Comment: Can you post your data (or at least a sample, perhaps `dput()`?

Comment: Also, if you didn't import your data into R-markdown, then R-markdown won't "see" it and cannot therefore plot it. You may already know that, but just in case...

Comment: Hi, at least for me, all the charts are appearing in the kaggle notebook. I can click on the "show hidden output" lines below each code block and it appears. 
Did you change something in the last hours? Can you try to view the kaggle notebook with another device ?

Comment: @RKeithL Hold on you might be cooking, when you say import the data into R-markdown is there like a setting or command I have to put to specifically do that? Because most of my other code does show up and you can see out puts but i don't know if there is something else I have to do.

Comment: @uke To work around the problem I manually saved my plots as pngs and then put them into the notebook which makes it look pretty normal, but at least for me when I've checked it if you show outputs on the charts specifically the blank charts still show up

Comment: @CMJeremyRay, in short: you must think of Markdown as "cut off" from your normal console work. So, even if you've created a df in your console, Markdown doesn't "see" it until you **separately** create/import the df within your Markdown code. Does that make sense? So in Markdown, prob in one of 1st chunks, add code to create/import whatever df you're working with.

Comment: I can confirm, it looks like your data object is not filled with anything, but it exists (otherwise there would be errors instead of blank plots). For example, everything is `NaN` in your descriptive stats output.

Comment: Just to follow up, @CMJeremyRay: did you get this sorted? Cheers!

Comment: @RKeithL I was able to work around the problem in Kaggle by manually uploading the images of the plots, I honestly still am not sure what the problem was but I am just gonna hope that it doesn't happen again lol. But I appreciate you very much for your help and thank you for following up with me

Comment: @CMJeremyRay, glad for a workaround pal. Cheers and good luck with the cert